# function return with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw this code on [this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-each-examples/): (it's an explainer for the $.each())

```
//ARRAYS
var arr = [ "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ];
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
       console.log(this);
       return (this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"
   });
//outputs: one two three
```

I'm not sure return about this line `(this != "three"); // will stop running after "three"`

Why will it stop running after `"three"`? Shouldn't it stop after the first run because `"one"` is not equal to `"three"`?

Comment: You are checking for `!=` so `one != three` is true

Comment: @ArunPJohny so it only returns when the expression evaluates to false -- interesting...

Answer (score 2):

```
return (this != "three");
```

so if `this` (current element of the array) is ever equals to `three` it will return false and the loop breaks and won't proceed further, otherwise it will continue iterating as it will return true.

```
return true; // means continue and
return false; // means break.
```

Comment: So return only happens when the expression in the parentheses evaluates to false? That's interesting... I thought it would happen when it evaluates to true.

Comment: @user1883050 you are getting it wrong, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

When `this` is anything but `"three"` the expression evaluates to `true` and so continues iterating.

So, for example.

```
this = "one";
(this != "three") = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of jQuery.each's **return** rule.

```
jQuery.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    return true; // It means continue;
    return false; // It means break;
});
```